# How to set static IPs for virtual machines if you are behind a router

Tags: router, virtual-machines, static-ip

I know that you can manually set static IPs on virtual machines, procedure dependent on the operating system.  However, if I am connected behind a router, I was told that DHCP could possibly dynamically assign an IP to that static IP.  How can I make sure that this doesn't happen?  My router is a ZyXel Prestige 900 series if that helps.

Comment: Sorry, but what?  Do you control the router?  DHCP does not get forwarded by routers without special configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't think of an instance where a DHCP takes over and inserts it's IP address over a statically bound address.  You initiate a DHCP request from the client, not from the server.